# Why in Qt Prjoect Settings in Qt Modules in QT SDK 5.0.2 some features are disabled?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012, qt5

please could anyone tell me why in Visual Studio when i create a project and after in QT Project Settings in QT Modules some features are disabled: 3D, Bluetooth, Contacts, Location, Organizer, Phonon, Publish and subscribe, Sensors, Service framework, System info, Versit? I`m using Visual Studio 2012, Qt 5.0.2 LGPL, Windows 8 x64.

Comment: Not all features are compiled in the binary distributions.  Are there any release notes installed which you can read?

Comment: I don`t know where to look... In include or lib there is no *blue (bluetooth) for example. Where i can find what components should be there?

Comment: I've been trying to find release notes myself, but have been unable (the digia website didn't respond).  I would have expected them to have been installed as part of the product, but I am not sure.  I know that OpenGL is not included in the Windows Qt 5.0.2 SDK, so I assume the other features are also disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Those modules are not part of Qt 5.0, either because they are not of good enough quality yet, or because nobody is actively maintaining them. Qt Sensors will be in Qt 5.1, but the others in your list won't be.

The list of official Qt 5.0 modules is at http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_5_Structure

Phonon is no longer part of Qt — it is maintained by KDE. However, the Qt Multimedia module is meant to be a replacement for Phonon.